# Regression model not successful-python

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I have to create a regression model in python

Energy ratings Vs. price and see whether energy ratings depend on price or not.

[image]

Here, is the data set and code below,

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# Initialise and fit linear regression model using `statsmodels`
model = smf.ols('price ~ energyrating', data=df)

model = model.fit()
```

The parameter I am getting is one negative, maybe that could be the reason for bad graph but not sure how to improve this.

```
model.params
#price=2.004943e+06 + (-.913381e+05)*energyrating

Intercept       2.004943e+06
energyrating   -3.913381e+05
dtype: float64
```

and creating the final model which was unsuccessful,

```
# Predict values
pred = model.predict()

# Plot regression against actual data
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(df['energyrating'], df['price'], 'o')           # scatter plot showing actual data
plt.plot(df['energyrating'], pred, 'r', linewidth=2)   # regression line
plt.xlabel('Energy ratings')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.title('Energy ratings Vs. Price')

plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I improve this? Is the data unstable or any logical error I am missing out on?

Thanks  in advance

EDIT:

Frequency graph of `energy rating`

[image]

This is how the energy rating is varying.

Comment: Is  the `energyrating`  column has values all equal to `3.9`? If that is the case, you cannot find a relation between `eneryrating` and `price`.

Comment: No, all values arent. I'll show its frequency graph please check the answer above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a simple `linear regression` cannot capture the relationship between `price` and `energyrating` from the plot you gave since `price` doesn't monotonically decrease or increase when `energyrating` increases. I suggest you include a quadratic term of `energyrating`, i.e., adding a new column of `energyrating * energyrating`, or other higher-order transformations you consider reasonable.

If you are allowed to use other models other than `linear regression`, I suggest you just average the `price` over each `energyrating`(it is discrete from your plot) bin and plot the curve, which I think would be nicer.

For example in pandas:

```
avg = df.groupby("energyrating")['price'].mean()
avg.plot()
```

Comment: Yes. I am allowed to use other models. ‘Just average the price over each energy rating’ how do I that.? Thank you

Comment: I didn't get that sentence

Comment: @kirti purohit Do you know how to use `pandas`?

Comment: Yes I use it everyday

Comment: Edited the answer to include a simple example. @kirti purohit

Comment: Thank you so much. It will be helpful for my analysis ahead!